# What does a number in parenthesis after a column declared in a MySQL table's foreign key represent?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, syntax, foreign-keys

I came across a MySQL (5.0.45-community-log) table the other day that produced a key as follows after printing a "SHOW CREATE TABLE " statement:

```
KEY `idx_object_relation_3` (`object_id`,`object_type`(4),`status`,`user_type_id`,`created_datetime`)
```

Could anyone explain to me what the "(4)" does in that KEY definition? Does it limit the number of characters retrieved from "object_type" sort of how the '1' parameter for TINYINT(1) would function?

The greater problem Im facing is that this table is copied to a few databases across different environments (such as development, staging, testing, production, etc), and in only one of these environments is this KEY defined. Attempting to drop the key resulted in nothing happening for a few hours, then a lost connection. Performance in just this one environment, regarding this table, is so slow that it is unusable (though the table has 5,453,757 records). Actions involving this table in environments where this KEY is not defined operate at acceptable speeds. There is no other difference between environments/databases regarding this table.

Comment: That's a version of MySQL from 2007, so it's no wonder performance is terrible. Upgrading to 5.6 should see a remarkable shift in speed.

Comment: Thanks, rub it in :). Currently working on a legacy codebase/system and not only do I not have the power to make such a change, but have been told that updating anything isnt really feasible for the foreseeable future (after strongly suggesting upgrading to modern versions of everything be a mission critical objective). For now, just doing what I can within the confines of 2006-2007 era webdev stack.

Comment: Well, if you've got performance problems, not going to be easy to solve them on a platform that's not just out of date, but no longer supported. MySQL is generally very good at updating, there's not much you have to do, and maintains excellent backwards compatibility. I've never had an issue updating MySQL before. I'd at least benchmark it on the newer engine to see if that'd yield anything useful. If not, you may need to update your hardware at great expense. Switching to SSD solves a lot of problems.

Comment: So anyways, back to the question....

Comment: My advice still stands. If they're running server software from 2007 they're putting themselves at severe risk, there are undoubtedly innumerable unpatched security problems with that system. Upgrading MySQL is usually a painless process, there's rarely complications, and I bet if you tested it on a newer version you'd find it's considerably faster. If it's "so slow it's unusable" then an upgrade is pretty much mandatory. A few hours of work could completely solve this problem.

Comment: Ok cool. I no longer work for this company. My question actually pertains to what that integer in parenthesis "(4)" means in the key. It does not ask about advice on how to or when to upgrade a DBMS. Can anyone answer the actual question?

Comment: That seemed like a side-note. One second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a hint like `(4)` indicates that only the first 4 letters of that field are indexed. Sometimes fields are way too long to index in their entirety so you need to focus on a subset.

This has enormous consequences on `UNIQUE` type indexes where that will only enforce uniqueness on the first N characters. If you're just concerned about order this is an optimization trick.